# How to properly manipulate variable

Tags: c#

So i'm trying to create a string variable that contains some text and a variable inside as well that gets the data from a textbox:

```
        string var1, var2;

        var1 = txt1.text;
        var2 = "some text" + var1 + "some text";
```

this is not so hard when i try it inside a button event but var2 is going to be used very often on my program and it has a lot of text inside. if possible i want to minimize declaring the variable over and over on every event needed. i would imagine it'd be easier if this could happen:

```
    string var1 = TextBox.Text;
    string var2 = "a lot of text" + var1 + "a lot of text";

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rtextbox.Text = "a lot of text" + var2;
    }
```

var2 would be used as a signature so i need to access it a lot of times. If there's an easier way then i'm open to suggestions.

when using the above code in declaring the variable i don't get an intellisense for the textbox so i'm getting an error. I need help so that i can declare the variable like the way illustrated above. I'm using vs2010. If using a higher version would help then i'll try it.

I have only touch the surface of c# programming so anything you see that might be disrepecting is not meant that way.

Comment: "i read that c# is not very friendly when it comes to global variables." - do you mean "C# developers tend not to use global variables, because global state is hard to manage, test and reason about"? To be honest, your whole question is hard to understand...

Comment: Basically, you have written the question and answer both in your question and you seem to be confused about it.

Comment: clearly trolling.. :)

Comment: when i use the above code when declaring the variable i get an error. Also when declaring this way the intelisense for the textbox doesn't appear. I apologize if my question was unclear or seems like it's trolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that when you change the value in the TextBox and call `var2`afterwards, you wish to see the *new* value. You can do that by using a function to return it, e.g.

```
private string GetFormattedTextBoxValue()
{
  string var1 = TextBox.Text;
  string var2 = "a lot of text" + var1 + "a lot of text";
  return var2;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    rtextbox.Text = "a lot of text" + GetFormattedTextBoxValue();
}
```

or if you want to reuse the logic, you can pass in the textbox:

```
private string GetFormattedTextBoxValue(System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textbox)
{
  string var1 = textbox.Text;
  string var2 = "a lot of text" + var1 + "a lot of text";
  return var2;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    rtextbox.Text = "a lot of text" + GetFormattedTextBoxValue(TextBox1);
}
```

or if it's always the same textbox you can make it a property and you don't need the brackets

```
private string FormattedTextBoxValue
{
  get
  {
    string var1 = TextBox.Text;
    string var2 = "a lot of text" + var1 + "a lot of text";
    return var2;
  }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    rtextbox.Text = "a lot of text" + FormattedTextBoxValue;
}
```

and then you can get rid of the temporary variables:

```
private string FormattedTextBoxValue
{
  get
  {
    return "a lot of text" + TextBox.Text + "a lot of text";
  }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    rtextbox.Text = "a lot of text" + FormattedTextBoxValue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion CompuChip.. will check this out and let you know.

Comment: Tested and working. It's a complete guide on how to do what i asked. Thanks CompuChip, now i'm having a better understanding on functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the variable in one place like this:

```
public static string var1, var2;
```

And then you can use it with classname.var1, where classname is the class where you declared var1.

Comment: I'll give this a shot.. will get back with you after i try this.

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to what you would want:

**NOT RECOMMENDED**

```
public static class GlobalVariables{
   public static string Var2 {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not clear from your question whether you want to use your **Var2** in all your forms or in a single form.If u want to use it in all your forms then better declare static class like this

```
static class GlobalClass
{
    private static string var2 = "";

    public static string Var2
    {
        get { return var2; }
        set { var2 = value; }
    }
}
```

And use it like this

```
GlobalClass.Var2 = "any string value";
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion shreesha. Will check this out and let you know what happens.